# Degree conditions for k-factor

Tags: extremal-graph-theory, graph-theory, matching-theory, co.combinatorics

I am looking for a simple degree conditon that ensures the existence of a k-factor in a graph. The k is supposed to be relatively high and I don't mind the condition being a bit strict. Ideally, something of the form $\delta(G) \geq f(k)$. Any suggestions? 10x!

To clarify a bit what I'm after: there is a theorem by Nishimura that ensures a k-factor for k not larger than n/4 or so. But I want a k-factor with k approaching n.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190160205/abstract

Comment: Note that $\delta(G) \geq f(k)$ will not do since there are graphs of arbitrarily high minimum degree without 1-factors (e.g $K_{2n+1}$).

Comment: You are right. What's the simplest I can get, then?

Comment: Hold on a sec: $K_{2n+1}$ does have a 2-factor, right?
So maybe it's still possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar theorem is proved in ["Relating minimum degree and the existence of a k-factor"](http://www.math.unl.edu/~shartke2/math/papers/min-deg-k-factor.pdf) by Hartke, Martin and Seacrest.

They show that a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices with minimum degree $\delta\geq \frac{n}{2}$ contains a $k$-factor if $kn$ is even and $$k< \frac{\delta+\sqrt{2\delta n-n^2+8}}{2}.$$

Moreover they show that this is optimal up to a small additive constant ($\le 1$). Notice that as $\delta\to n$ we have $k\to n$, as well.

Comment: Following your lead, I also googled now this paper:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.0202.pdf